# JavaScript sorting function not sorting correctly

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I'm very new to javascript and coding in general so bear with me. I have an array of javascript objects with around 1000 total entries. Each array row holds information about meteors that have impacted Earth.

```
<table class="table table-striped">
            <tr  class="bg-info">
                <th data-colname="date" data-order="desc"> Date/Time (UT) &#9650</th>
                <th data-colname="latitude">Latitude (deg) &#9650</th>
                <th data-colname="longitude" data-order="desc">Longitude (deg) &#9650</th>
                <th data-colname="altitude" data-order="desc">Altitude (km) &#9650</th>
                <th data-colname="velocity" data-order="desc">Velocity (km/s) &#9650</th>
                <th data-colname="vx" data-order="desc">vx &#9650</th>
                <th data-colname="vy" data-order="desc">vy &#9650</th>
                <th data-colname="vz" data-order="desc">vz &#9650</th>
                <th data-colname="radiatedEnergy" data-order="desc">Total Radiated Energy (J) &#9650</th>
                <th data-colname="impactEnergy" data-order="desc">Calculated Total Impact Energy (kt) &#9650</th>
            </tr>
    
            <tbody id="myTable"> </tbody>
        </table>


var myArray = [
            {'date': '2022-09-14 23:31:15' ,'latitude': '40.8N' ,'longitude': '63.4E'  ,'altitude': '35.8' ,'velocity': '17.4' ,'vx': '-13.9' ,'vy': '-4.3'  ,'vz': '9.5'   ,'radiatedEnergy': '15.2e10'   ,'impactEnergy': '0.11'},
            {'date': '2013-02-15 03:20:33' ,'latitude': '54.8N' ,'longitude': '61.1E'  ,'altitude': '23.3' ,'velocity': '18.6' ,'vx': '+12.8' ,'vy': '-13.3' ,'vz': '-2.4'  ,'radiatedEnergy': '3.75e14'  ,'impactEnergy': '440'},
            {'date': '2018-12-18 23:48:20' ,'latitude': '56.9N' ,'longitude': '172.4E' ,'altitude': '26.0' ,'velocity': '13.6' ,'vx': '6.3'   ,'vy': '-3.0'  ,'vz': '-31.2' ,'radiatedEnergy': '3.13e13'  ,'impactEnergy': '49'},
         ]
buildTable(myArray)
```

The array is then sorted and built onto a webpage with html.

```
$('th').on('click', function(){         
        var column = $(this).data('colname')
        var order = $(this).data('order')
        var text = $(this).html()
        text = text.substring(0, text.length - 1);
     
        if(order == 'desc') {
            $(this).data('order', "asc")
            myArray = myArray.sort((a,b) => a[column] > b[column] ? 1 : -1)
            text += '&#9660'     //appends triangle symbol based on ascending or descending            

        }else {
            $(this).data('order', "desc")
            myArray = myArray.sort((a,b) => a[column] < b[column] ? 1 : -1)
            text += '&#9650'
        }

    $(this).html(text)
    buildTable(myArray)
    })

                
    function buildTable(data){
        var table = document.getElementById('myTable')
        table.innerHTML = ''   

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
            var colname = `num-${i}`
            var row = `<tr>
                <td>${data[i].date}</td>
                <td>${data[i].latitude}</td>
                <td>${data[i].longitude}</td>
                <td>${data[i].altitude}</td>
                <td>${data[i].velocity}</td>
                <td>${data[i].vx}</td>
                <td>${data[i].vy}</td>
                <td>${data[i].vz}</td>
                <td>${data[i].radiatedEnergy}</td>
                <td>${data[i].impactEnergy}</td>
            </tr>`
        table.innerHTML += row
            }
        }
```

The problem is I need this sorting algorithm to work for 2 of the most important columns, which it currently isn't, being radiatedEnergy and impactEnergy. How can I modify this sorting algorithm to sort radiatedEnergy values so that 3.75e14 > 15.2e10?

Also I can't figure out why impactEnergy sorting seems to only check the first number instead of the entire value.

[image of impactEnergy column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTb44.png)

I've tried different sorting algorithms to include parameters that would fit this data but none of them are working. For radiatedEnergy I need the algorithm to differentiate between e10, e11, e12, etc. For impactEnergy I'm lost as to why it is not checking the entire value. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `(a, b) => a[column].localeCompare(b[column])` sorts ascending, `(a, b) => b[column].localeCompare(a[column])` sorts descending. If you’re dealing with numbers, `(a, b) => a[column] - b[column]` sorts ascending, `(a, b) => b[column] - a[column]` sorts descending. Why does `myArray` contain numbers as strings? If they were actual numbers, you could also consider `(a, b) => (b[column] < a[column]) - (a[column] < b[column])` to sort generically (lexicographically or numerically).

Comment: The values are treated as text and string comparison is used instead of numbers. Try representing the values as numbers.

Comment: Remove the single quotes in the numbers in your myArray declaration. For example, use 3.13e13 instead of '3.13e13'

Comment: @Shameel This worked! However when removing the single quotes from the numbers with e in them, it sorts it correctly but displays the entire value with many zeros. Is there a way to sort it correctly but only display it in a shorter form? Thank you.

Comment: @aljames24 I have posted this as an answer and added the requested information, Please check.

Comment: @aljames24 I have posted this as an answer and added the requested information, Please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the number is enclosed in single quotes, it is treated as text and string comparison is used instead of number comparison.

1. Remove single quote from the numbers in your array declaration.
2. Use number.toExponential() method to display the number in exponential form.